# Is there an Excel auto calculate that can figure out missing nr. based on value at the end

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Here is an example]

Is there a way to make Excel automatically calculate all the missing nr. based on activities which are given (+, -, *, / etc.) and then it would fill all the necessary whole nr. without commas. He would say A1 is that A2 is this A3 is that etc.
See the example for visual information. I don't know how to describe this correctly in English.

Comment: Not with formula.  Maybe with VBA and just plugging in number till it satisfices the rules, but even that would be many loops.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use vba code that executes on sheet update within your excel

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
```

This needs to be within the sheet in question, not a separate module

Then within that, detect which cells are populated and which are undetermined, using Isempty() would be a rough starting point - you'd likely want an isnumeric check too. Then for the undetermined cells, use

```
Cells(1,1).GoalSeek Goal:=cells(2,1)
```

Obviously swapping out the addresses as suitable.

Not sure if it'll not like the formula dependencies - if so, depending on which cells are empty, you can redefine the formulae within VBA, i.e

```
cells(1,1) = "=RC2+RC3"
```